# Stored Procedure Returns 0

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures, return-value

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server which looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsPer]
(
    @person_fname VARCHAR(50),
    @person_lname VARCHAR(50),
    @person_initials VARCHAR(50),
    @person_mono VARCHAR(15),
    @person_pemail VARCHAR(50),
    @status INT
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    INSERT INTO [tbl_person] ([person_fname], [person_lname], [person_initials], [person_mono], [person_pemail], [status]) 
    VALUES (@person_fname, @person_lname, @person_initials, @person_mono, @person_pemail, @status);

    SELECT 
        person_id, person_fname, person_lname, person_initials, person_mono, 
        person_pemail, status 
    FROM 
        tbl_person 
    WHERE 
        (person_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

I am using this stored procedure in ASP.NET Web API with Entity Framework.

I need to get the inserted `person_id`, but it always returns 0.

Once I get the `person_id` I want to perform different action based on that. But not getting the result.

Here is my ASP.NET code

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostPer([FromBody] tbl_person Per)
{
        using (var context = new Entities())
        {
            var response = context.spInsPer(Per.person_fname, Per.person_lname, Per.person_initials, Per.person_mono, Per.person_pemail, Per.status);

            var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, Per);
            message.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri + response.ToString());

            return message;
        }
}
```

Given below is output when executing the SP.

[image]

Comment: have you set up the table to be identity / auto-increment?

Comment: Yes it is set for identity

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the table you're inserting to is configured for identity / auto-increment.

That would explain why the primary key [person_id] isn't getting incremented. You can test this by inserting manually... and see if the person_id is auto populated..

Comment: Here is my table. CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_person](
 [person_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [person_fname] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [person_lname] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [person_initials] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [person_mono] [varchar](15) NULL,
 [person_pemail] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [status] [int] NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_person] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [person_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: I've edited the question with output screenshot. Pls check.